# Actions Listeners for one button

Tags: java, swing

If i pressed first time on a button it will output massage dialog "Screen saved" 
if i pressed others times on a button it will output massage dialog "Screen saved on a desctop." I just don`t know how to do this. I tried with labels,with if constructions, but its still not working, help me.

```
screenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                  window.getWidth(),
                  window.getHeight(),
                  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
                  );
        window.paint( image.getGraphics() );            
        try {
            File temp = File.createTempFile("screenshot", ".png");
            ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File(getDir(),"screen.png"));

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(" ");
        } 
        if (showDialog==false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(screenButton, "Screen saved");
        }
    }
});
if (showDialog) {

    screenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(screenButton,"Screen saved on a desctop");
            showDialog=true;        
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Change `} catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(" "); ..` to `} catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(); ..` for more useful debugging. Implement **logging** for even *more* useful debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to add two ActionListeners to the same button.

The logic should be self contained in a single `ActionListener`. Then you use a `Boolean` variable to determine which process to do.

Something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    private boolean firstTime = true;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (firstTime)
        {
            System.out.println( "First Message" );
            firstTime = false;
        }
        else
            System.out.println( "Another Message" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i trying to do this when i don`t come to the Stack Oveflow.And its wasn`t work.Magic people here.Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you declared your boolean `showDialog`, but I will try to explain the basic principle to solve your problem.

```
boolean showDialog = false;

if(!showDialog) {
 //Show the first dialog
 showDialog = true;
}
if(showDialog){
//show the second dialog
showDialog = false;
}
```

Your problem was, that you forgot to change the value of `showDialog`.

```
if (showDialog==false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(screenButton, "Screen saved");
            showDialog = true; //You forgot this line
    }
```

Because after the first `if` the `showDialog` boolean is still `false` and your second `if` can only be reached if `showDialog` is true.

Comment: not working, if i clicked on a button first, i want to see screen save, if i clicked every next time i want to see screen saved on a desctop